# How do I fix the red lines on Altium schematic?

Tags: pcb, altium

I have been trying to get rid of the red lines in the screenshot near the push and LRD wires. I have made sure the wire is connected and everything but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.
I have tried to use the "annotate schematic quietly" option as well but nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Top tip for your readers: print screen is a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Three possibilities:

1. The nets have no other instances in the schematic and therefore they are floating, or
2. The signals coming to directional pins (i.e. inputs, outputs or bidirectional GPIOs) are coming from non-directional pins (e.g. push buttons - normally you don't define direction for a button's pins), or
3. The types of the signals (i.e. power or signal) don't match.

Either case these nets will be indicated with red underlines.

Answer (score 3):

Check that everything is on your grid properly, because it's telling you that some of your net labels are floating and not properly on your wires, which is why some of your nets only have one connection and you're getting the red underlines.